# O(1) space complexity for odd-even

Tags: python, arrays, time-complexity, space-complexity

I'm reordering the entries of an array so that the even ones (divisible by 2) appear first. The code snippet is as follows:

```
def even_odd(A):
    next_even , next_odd = 0, len(A) - 1
    while next_even < next_odd:
        if A[next_even] % 2 == 0:
           next_even += 1
        else:
           A[next_even], A[next_odd] = A[next_odd], A[next_even]
           next_odd -= 1
```

The time complexity is given as **O(N)** which I'm guessing is because I'm going through the whole array? But how's the space complexity **O(1)**?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-86/

Comment: The space complexity is O(1) because the algorithm uses the same amount of memory, regardless of the size of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a fixed amount of space to reorder the list.  That, by definition, is **O(1)**.  The fact that you're *dealing* with the length of `A` does not count against your function's space usage: `A` was already allocated by the problem definition.  All you have added to that is two integers, `next_even` and `next_odd`: they are your **O(1)**.

---

UPDATE per OP comment

The size of `A` does not "count against" your space complexity, as your algorithm uses the space already provided by the calling program.  You haven't added any.

Sorry; I didn't realize you had an open question about the time complexity.  Yes, your guess is correct: you go through the `while` loop `N-1` times (`N = len(A)` ); each iteration takes no more than a constant amount of time. Therefore, the time complexity is bounded by `N`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this: A was already allocated by the problem definition? Also, what about the time complexity?

Answer (score -1):

I guess the meaning here that the "additional" memory required for the reordering is o(1), excluded the original array.